# Menu Not Collapsing on Small Devices

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

It is my understanding that all list items inside of:

```
<div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
```

should collapse into a single menu at a defined breakpoint. I have been troubleshooting the below code for several hours and cannot find why it is not working:

```
<header>
  <link href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/cloudserv.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="{{STATIC_URL}}/img/favicon.ico"/>
</header>

<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-responsive-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"><img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}img/logo.png"></img></a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      {% for category in main_menu %}
      {%  if category.item_set.all %}
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="{{ category.url_name }}" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">{{ category.name }}<b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="/{{ category.url_name }}">{{ category.name }}</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            {% for item in category.item_set.all %}
            <li><a href="/{{ category.url_name }}/{{ item.url_name }}">{{ item.name }}</a></li>
            {% endfor %}  
          </ul>
        </li>
        {% else %}   
        <li><a href="/{{ category.url_name }}">{{ category.name }}</a></li>
        {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

*Please note that all code contained inside of brackets is related to Django's templating system.*
*Also, all relevant Bootstrap files have been included and all other aspects of the menu appear to be working fine.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.navbar-toggle`'s `data-target` attribute needs to target the `collapse` div. Since it has an ID of `navbar` you can target it using a CSS style selector like `data-target="#navbar"`

Before

```
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-responsive-collapse">
```

After

```
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar">
```

UPDATE:

You are also missing the meta tag below in you `head`.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

You need this for mobile devices, otherwise mobile browsers will zoom out and you will not get the mobile breakpoints.

Comment: I attempted editing the code as suggested but is still is not working. I also tried changing my navbar-collapse div to ""navbar-collapse collapse navbar-responsive-collapse"

Comment: @socialdtk See this example http://jsfiddle.net/SchmalzyB/y372tcwe/, it works with your code (and my suggested change). Did you also include jQuery before your bootstrap.js file?

Comment: @socialdtk the included files look correct... But it would be more helpful to see the actual HTML output of the code, instead of the server-side code.

Comment: @socialdtk The navbar on the URL you provided is working correctly. Maybe I am not understanding what your issue is. Your navbar collapses as expected, and can be expanded with the toggle button, so I'm not sure what the issue is...

Comment: Maybe it just isn't working with the phone that I'm testing with (Galaxy S4). If that is the case I'd suspect that I can resolve the issue by adjusting the breakpoint within the CSS?

Comment: That's exactly what it was! Thank you!!

Comment: @socialdtk no prob. If you are going to use bootstrap, use thier starter template -> http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#template